Определение возможностей конкретного неизвестного компилятора С и С++
Как программно на С и/или С++ получить полную информацию(всё поддерживаемые типы, функции, макросы и т.д.) о возможностях конкретного неизвестного компилятора, в т.ч. встроенного в известную IDE(например CxxDroid v.5.2 и др.)?

Вопрос странно поставлен. Компиляторов мало (популярных три штуки: Clang, GCC, MSVC). По специфичным макросам определяете, какой их трех у вас, и его версию, потом смотрите в https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Функции, определенные в стандарте С++ сгруппированы на фичи. Для каждой фичи есть свой макрос: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test по ним можно определить наличие соответствующей группы функций.

@HolyBlackCat, вы не упомянули ещё 11 известных компиляторов от фирм, не говоря уж о куче "самопальных"(на github их, как min 3), поэтому вопрос задан столь широко! А вопрос возник при обнаружении поддержки компилятором нестандартных типов С/С++. Ваш ответ только под известные компиляторы, а вопрос стоял шире - неизвестный, в т.ч. и "самопальный"! Подскажите как определить сведения о компиляторе(хотя бы min), если он встроен в IDE?

В плюсах есть feature test macros для новых фичей. Все, больше ничего нет. В описании cxxdroid в гугл-плее написано, что они используют патченый Clang. Версию можно узнать через std::cout << __clang_version__ << '\n';.

Если нужного макроса в списке выше нет, то есть только два выхода - читать мануал от компилятора, или пробовать скомпилировать программу с нужной фичей и смотреть на результат. Перебирать все известные компиляторы их специфичными макросами - не такая уж плохая идея. Если посмотреть на список компиляторов на cppreference, то там, не считая gcc и msvc, половина - форки clang-a (intel C++, IBM XL C++, C++ Builder, nvcc), а остальные - это какая-то жутко редкая фигня.

@HolyBlackCat & @ Chorkov, Спасибо! Буду разбираться и, возможно, в процессе этого появятся допвопросы!

@HolyBlackCat, можно ли, как с clang узнать версию другого компилятора, например, gcc, т.е. gcc_version? Как узнать какие стандарты С/С++ он может поддерживать и на какой настроен в данное время(без ключей)?

Про версию другого компилятора - не понял. Какая версия стандарта - напечатайте __cplusplus и посмотрите, какой там год указан. Какие поддерживает - попробовать разные ключи -std=c++?? и посмотреть, вылетает ошибка или нет.

@HolyBlackCat, переформулирую: можно ли узнать версию другого компилятора по формату, как для clang, просто поменяв clang на те, что известны, например, gcc? В Cxxdroid в установках показывает какие std C/C++ он поддерживает, если ввести неправильно установку, но это частный случай, а хотелось бы сделать программный запрос, как общий случай. А не зная какой компилятор, можно(как?) запросить у него самого написать своё название?

"А не зная какой компилятор, можно(как?) запросить у него самого написать своё название?" -- можно вызвать (скажем, через  popen) с ключами типа --version, --help и поразбирать вывод. Если файл, который стоит за командой вызова компилятора (скажем, cc в linux) это symbolic link, то можно пройтись по линкам (и обнаружить в конце-концов, что cc это gcc)  / (зачем на практике все это нужно, не представляю. Например, мне вполне хватает gcc, тем более, что он есть для всех платформ)

@avp, спасибо, но ваш ответ частного характера, ибо 'popen' только в Unix-Like OS. У меня в CxxDroid v.5.2 в dir стоит 'gcc', однако по формату запроса(см.выше) о версии, со вставкой 'gcc' выдаёт ошибку, а со вставкой 'clang' выдаёт версию! Ещё странность: по запросу об установленном std C++ выдаёт 201707, хотя там выставлен в настройках std=c++2a (типа с++20). Я проверил типом 'char8_t' (поддержка с std c++20) и всё нормально, по сравнению с ошибкой для предустановленного std c++17, т.е. std c++2a похоже переходной и почти std c++20 2020г.

@Reason, по крайней мере в винде (как показывает гугл) popen есть. А в какой используемой вами ОС (среде программирования) его нет?

@HolyBlackCat, я нашол сегодня ещё один способ(кроме чтения документации и компиляции с фичей) - это использование макрос-ключей компилятора и по ним можно узнать какие команды, ключи и макросы-ключи он поддерживает и выводить инфу о нём и под какие процессоры он компилирует! Беда в том, что я не знаю, как программно запустить режим терминала(командной строки) для получения инфы таким путём! Может на примере покажите?

@Reason, если под "это использование макрос-ключей компилятора" вы подразумеваете вывод вот такой строки echo | gcc -dM -E -, то ее можно запустить просто через popen (затем прочесть и разобрать вывод). (На всякий случай, таким образом можно выполнить несколько команд, разделяя их ; (похоже, вам надо просто разобраться, как работает sh -c 'commands list'))

@avp, нет, не такая строка, а, вообще, под макрос-ключ я подразумеваю утилиту, вызываемую как ключ компилятора. Отличие здесь в том, что обычные утилиты оформлены как функции и их можно запустить программно в софте, а эту утилиту(ключ-макрос) - только в составе компилятора, как ключ, а для этого нужен режим терминала.

@Reason, вместо массы наукоподобных слов приведите конкретный пример (символы, которые вы набиваете в терминале). Может после этого станет понятно, что именно вы хотите

@avp, вы, похоже, опытный "волчара" по С/С++, но что-то слегка "тормозите"! У меня почему-то в моих вопросах нет редактора, а в чужих - он есть, поэтому я лишон возможности легко цитировать и т.д., а главное выкладывать код без урезаний. Имейте это ввиду. Поясняю:в терминале, запустив команду: "clang --help_hidden", на монитор выдаются все ключи и ключи-макросы + ключи при отладки софта, поддерживаемые данным компилятором.Так вот это и кучу другого я хотел бы(вывод инфы) получить в создаваемом софте о возможностях конкретного компилятора, но не знаю как в софте переключиться в режим терминала.

@Reason, выполните простой тест в своей программе -- напишите system("clang --help_hidden");. Появится ли у вас в выводе (в stdout) тот же текст, что вы видите, запуская эту команду в терминале?

@avp, попробовал, как в потоке()std::cout <<, так и без него, так в обоих случаях пишит, что обнаружен не определённый идентификатор 'clang' и не ругает, если нет ';' перед ' return 0', а значит надо подключить 'lib', где он определён, но где? Но самое интересное, если включить ошибочно написанную 'lib'( вместо ), то компилятор не видит этой ошибки и отсутствие ';', но ругается, что файл 'stdio' не найден!

@Reason, кто пишет про идентификатор clang? Если компилятор, то вы пишете что-то совсем не то. Вообще, похоже, что manpages (тут man system) вы читать не приучены

@avp, так вы же не указали, что надо использовать 'man system', вот я и не использовал это, ибо я только на днях столкнулся с Linux и, естественно, мало что знаю про неё без конкретизации использования того-то и того из неё!

@Reason, похоже, что все-таки для начала вам надо поучиться (лучше в линуксе). Прочтите K&R. Затем: 1. Выполните все упражнения из нее: 2 Напишите сами (не заглядывая в чужой код) реализации всех libc функций из нее.  И да, это обязательно -- забудьте про все IDE, код собирайте из командной строки (можете освоить make -- это будет полезно)

@avp, спасибо за рекомендации по изучению!

@avp, вы хитрец - для вас написать правильный ответ легко, как сплюнуть, но вы пожелали  прикинуться "тормозом" и решили проверить, смогу ли я сам решить задачку! Помучался я немного, "включил" соображалку и решил задачу - всё запустил, причём в процессе выявил в описании system() на man7.org 2 ошибки, характерные для профи:1)Явно не указано, что в софте запускаемую  команду надо заключать между 2х 2х кавычек;2)В описании после включений библиотек указана декларация system() и она ошибочна в том, что этого не надо делать в софте, иначе "вылазят" ошибки. Профи разберутся, а вот новички - нет!

@Reason, вы уже прочли книжку и выполнили все упражнения из нее?

@avp, уж больно вы шустрый - нет, конечно! Но у меня скачана, как указанное вами 2е, так я ещё скачал 3е издание, т.ч., со временем, прочту. А, вообще, почти 5 лет назад я прочёл Шилдта и при не знании С++, нашол у него кучу ошибок, а его одну книгу, в шутку, называю "Самый полный ошибок справочник по С++"! Неужели он сам их делает или при переводе и наборе делают это?! Да, недавно узнал про него, что он не спец и даже появился термин-ругательство про него!

@Reason, ну, кто такие Керниган и Ритчи вы наверняка слышали

@avp, ясное дело - Ритчи с Томсоном создали С, а уж Страуструп доработал до С++. Вы загляните в вопросы по С/С++ - я там задал очень сложный вопрос об особенностях С/С++!

@avp, не подскажите ли в следующем: в потоковом выводе в С++ ч/з system() запускал команды posix compatible os и потом popen echo clang -dM -E-, так выдаёт: sh: posix или popen: not found 32512. И о чём это говорит? Неужели в моей ОС нет этих команд что ли? И почему добавлены цифры? Да, попробовал вывести это в С и столкнулся с тем, что потокового ввода/вывода в С нет(есть консольный и файловый). Как это сделать в С?

Я думаю, вы просто что-то не то наформатировали в строке, которую передаете в popen.
Вот самый простой вариант на Си, практически без проверок (у менят нет clang, использую gcc, но это не принципиально...)
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  FILE *f = popen("echo | gcc -dM -E -", "r");
  if (f) {
    char s[1000];
    int n = 0;
    while (fgets(s, 1000, f)) {
      n++;
      printf("%4d %s", n, s);
    }

    pclose(f);
  }

  return puts("\nEnd") == EOF;
}

Компилирую и запускаю:
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/Bailkal/tst$ gcc t-popen.c && ./a.out 
   1 #define __SSP_STRONG__ 3
   2 #define __DBL_MIN_EXP__ (-1021)
   3 #define __FLT32X_MAX_EXP__ 1024
   4 #define __UINT_LEAST16_MAX__ 0xffff
   5 #define __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE 2
.....
.....
 344 #define __INT_LEAST64_WIDTH__ 64
 345 #define __UINT_FAST8_TYPE__ unsigned char
 346 #define __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL 4
 347 #define __ATOMIC_RELEASE 3

End
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/Bailkal/tst$ 

Что вы называете потоковым вводом-выводом, которого вроде бы нет в Си, я не понимаю. Обычно FILE * также называют и потоком ... (вообще, для большинства подобных программ, которые последовательно читают данные, совершенно не важно с чем именно (терминалом, pipe, socket, файл на диске и т.д. и т.п.) связан FILE *)
(K&R еще не прочли?)

СПАСИБО! Подставил clang и всё работает. А что эта прога выдаёт? Макросы данного компилятора что ли или ОС? Потоковый ввод/вывод в С++ это cin/cout, который открывается и закрывается автоматически, а то, что вы применили выше в С - это, похоже, файловый ввод/вывод, который есть в С++, но чуть по-другому.

Аналог cin/cout это уже автоматически открытые FILE * stdin/stdout.  Прога выдает макросы компилятора, естественно, именно то, о чем вы много раз спрашивали в куче своих вопросов. Вы все же книги читать думаете или собираетесь чему-то научиться в режиме вопрос-ответ?

кроме поддерживаемых компилятором макросов, я уже научился получать и кучу другой инфы о компиляторе и буду продолжать дальше, пока "не выжму" всё, что можно, а потом попробую унивесальнизировать, распространив на различные компиляторы и в разных ОС! Ну, а книжки, конечно, я буду читать и учиться на вопросах/ответах, т.б. одно другому не мешает. Вам тоже посоветую полистать книжки по устойчивости и безопасности софта, если захотите ответить на мои вопросы на эту тему и задам я их, как позволит система, т.е., думаю, завтра.

@Reason, по поводу книжек по устойчивости и безопасности софта могу вам сразу ответить -- люди которые их пишут сами пишут в основном диссертации, а не рабочий софт. Вообще, в IT все очень соответствует известной поговорке -- "кто умеет работать руками, тот работает, кто не умеет работать, тот идет руководить работниками, у кого и руководить не получается, тот учит правильно работать и руководить" (только вместо рук в IT используется голова...)

а если и учить правильно работать и руководить не получается, то что тогда ему делать? А насчёт головы - так она у всех есть да только очень мало её используют для анализа и мышления, а большинство и не знает об этом и предпочитают использовать её для бадания!
